# Animation of label and buttons on the screen from left to right side in cocos2d app

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Currently, I have looking for an cocos2d game app. I want to display score sliding from left to right side and buttons sliding from right to left side on the screen  after that when game complete and score will display on the  score screen display to user.

Comment: and what is your problem? that did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can moved lable as well as Button move in left to right you can use this code:-

**in .h Class:-**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)CCLabelTTF              *Result_lable;
```

**in .m class:-**

```
@synthesize Result_lable;

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
    Result_lable = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"lable" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
            Result_lable.position =ccp(160, 280);
            [self addChild:Result_lable];

     id move1 =[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(0, 0)];

            id move2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(320, 0)];

            id repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:move1,move2, nil]];

            [Result_lable runAction:repeat];

    }
}
```

Do the same for Button (ccmenuItem) also hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. that code works for me and solve the problem.